# Can we put multiple page directives on single jsp page?

Tags: jsp

Sir, When we create JSP page using eclipse then a page directive is automatically created (<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; set=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>) and I want to generate another  exception page for it, how can i do the same?

Comment: How about... just doing it and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks sir for giving me instant reply. I have written the code like
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page errorPage="errPage.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
and after executing my jsp page , i found error http 500 internal server error.

Comment: And what does the error say? Does it change anything if you just add the `errorPage="errPage.jsp"` to the existing page directive?

Comment: •The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.<br>
the above text is displayed when i run my jsp page.

Comment: and Sir when i remove the <%@ page errorPage="errPage.jsp" %> , then after running this jsp page, it gives excption on the same page and i want to show all the exceptions on errPage.jsp page. plz help?